# Sort by a column in a has one relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, has-many, has-one

I have a Model (Activity) with a `has_one` relation to another Model (OverallRating) which has a column called `overall` I want to sort the `Activities` based on the `overall` column. I have searched about this but was unlucky and found very specific stuff that aren't really as simple as my question here.

Answer (score 1):

That will do for has_one:

```
Activities.joins(:overall_rating).order('overall_ratings.overall').uniq
```

I am pretty sure this will also work for has_many association (just add an s to the symbol in `joins` method) however has not tested it yet.

Comment: It actually didn't work. I'm sure you didn't test that. 
What worked for me was this `Activity.joins(:overall_rating).select("activities.*").order('overall')` I'll add it and mark it as answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to BroiSatse he gave me a headstart. However this is what worked for me.

`Activity.joins(:overall_rating).select("activities.*").order('overall')`